# How would I redirect to a profile page based on the description below?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I know that what I'm asking probably has a simple solution... but I am a beginner to PHP and (I consider myself) intermediate with HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

What I need to know how to do:

I need to redirect from https://example.com/@user to the @user's profile page.
I figure I'll need help from htaccess and php. Thank you for any help!

UPDATE:::: I remembered, I will be using php to call the profile's information from a database. So what I need (i think) is to know how make htaccess read the "@" and extract the value after the "@". In my MySql database, the username is the name of a table. So, i'd take the "@" value and call data from the table. After doing so, I would load the data into the website, without changing the url, or giving everyone a separate profile page, to avoid slowing down my website and taking up too much space. Does this make sense?

going for something like https://instagram.com/@bobfromchurch
the @ and username.

Comment: Unrelated, "_the username is the name of a table_" sounds like bad database design to me

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and then use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's (which you set up in your application) instead of adding a bunch of different rules in your htaccess. It's how most frameworks and CMS's do it. And since you only need one single rule (that redirects all requests to non-existing files to index.php), it's easier to move it between web servers (not all use htaccess). Most routers support dynamic arguments, which would fit what you're trying to do.

Comment: @M.Eriksson All that I need to do is perform a mysql query on the username entered in the url bar. after the @ symbol. Then, without redirecting, I need it to load the data of the selected user.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER TO MY QUESTION:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^@(.*)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

simple! Thank you!

Comment: You are allowing an optional trailing slash on the URL, eg. `/@user/` and `/@user` will both successfully match the regex `^@(.*)/?$`. However, you are capturing the slash in the `$1` backreference, so these will end up rewriting to different URLs. Maybe you're filtering this in your PHP script, but you can avoid capturing the optional trailing slash by making the capturing subpattern non-greedy. ie. `^@(.*?)/?$`. But unless you specifically want to allow an empty username, you should at least be using the `+` quantifier (1 or more) instead of `*` (0 or more).

Comment: Just to add... the filesystem checks are likely redundant, unless you have actual files and directories that start with `@`?

Comment: @MrWhite You see, now my htaccess redirects `example.com/@user` to `example.com/@user`. It is now a valid page. I don't understand how exactly it works. I copy/paste everything in my htaccess file. But with that, I can read the url using php. I can then delete everything up to (and) `@`. After that, I can check mysql for the username value.